# php sorting array's - ksort after array_merge doesn't makes any diference

Tags: php

I've been struggling with this for a couple of hours and can't make this happen.
I've 2 arrays of holidays, the ones with a specific date and the ones such as easter who aren't fixed.
I want to merge both and sort them by date, I'm using mm-dd

How can I achieve this?

my code

```
$feriados_nacionais = array(
    $janeiro = array("01-01" => "Dia de Ano Novo"),
    $fevereiro = array(),
    $marco = array(),
    $abril = array("04-25" => "Dia da Liberdade"),
    $maio = array("05-01" => "Dia do trabalhador"),
    $junho = array("06-10" => "Dia de Portugal, dia de Camões e das Comunidades"),
    $julho = array(),
    $agosto = array("08-15" => "Assunção de Nossa Senhora"),
    $setembro = array(),
    $outubro = array("10-05" => "Implantação da República"),
    $novembro = array("11-01" => "Dia de todos os Santos"),
    $dezembro = array("12-01" => "Dia da Restauração da Independência", "12-08" => "Dia da Imaculada Conceição", "12-25" => "Dia de Natal")
);

$feriados_moveis  = array(
    array($sexta_feira_santa => "Sexta-feira Santa"),
    array($dia_e_mes_pascoa => "Domingo de Páscoa"),
    array($corpo_de_deus => "Corpo de Deus")
);

$feriados_nacionais = array_merge($feriados_nacionais, $feriados_moveis);
ksort($feriados_nacionais);
print_r($feriados_nacionais);
```

output

```
Array ( [01-01] => Dia de Ano Novo )
Array ( )
Array ( )
Array ( [04-25] => Dia da Liberdade )
Array ( [05-01] => Dia do trabalhador )
Array ( [06-10] => Dia de Portugal, dia de Camões e das Comunidades )
Array ( )
Array ( [08-15] => Assunção de Nossa Senhora )
Array ( )
Array ( [10-05] => Implantação da República )
Array ( [11-01] => Dia de todos os Santos )
Array ( [12-01] => Dia da Restauração da Independência [12-08] => Dia da Imaculada Conceição [12-25] => Dia de Natal )
Array ( [03-29] => Sexta-feira Santa )
Array ( [03-31] => Domingo de Páscoa )
Array ( [05-30] => Corpo de Deus )
```

Please note that even after ksort the last 3 items are still in the end of the output

Any help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Apply `var_dump` to your array just before `ksort` to see what you are really about to sort.

Comment: Not sure why in the array you are using the following method of setting data `$janeiro = array("...`

Comment: var_dump returns 14 entries like 14 => 
    array (size=1)
      '05-30' => string 'Corpo de Deus' (length=13)

Comment: You sort array which values are __arrays__.

Comment: Mr Nigel I've tried without the $Janeiro... as just use them because it's easy to read and stay organised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line to fix is:

```
$feriados_nacionais = array_merge(...array_merge($feriados_nacionais, $feriados_moveis));
```

Without variadic (`...`) arguments support:

```
$feriados_nacionais = call_user_func_array(
    'array_merge', 
    array_merge($feriados_nacionais, $feriados_moveis)
);
```

Comment: Mr Mulder, thanks a ton for help! applying 2 times the array_merge deletes empty arrays and then ksort does work. For me it is the first time using variadic (...). just another question, is it wrong to use the $janeiro = array(), does it interfere with anything?

Comment: It just assigns empty array to $janeiro, if you don't need $janeiro variable, you can just use array()